# Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "mitten" und "in der Mitte"?

Tags: translation, word-usage, difference, german-to-english

Was ist der Unterschied, wenn ich sage...

> Mitten der Brücke finden Sie...

oder

> In der Mitte der Brücke finden Sie...

***Ganz egal?***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nein, es ist nicht egal. Aber erstmal: Bei *Mitten der Brücke* fehlt die notwendige Präposition.

> Mitten *auf* der Brücke finden Sie …

**Irgendwo** auf der Brücke – nur nicht genau am Rand – finden Sie etwas, was Sie da normalerweise nicht erwarten.

> In der Mitte der Brücke finden Sie …

Sie finden ziemlich genau in der Mitte der Brücke etwas.

---

**Mitten** hat also mit einer Ortsangabe nur beiläufig etwas zu tun. Es drückt eher aus, dass etwas ins Auge sticht.

> **Mitten** auf dem Feld steht eine einsame Vogelscheuche.
>
> Der Vogel hat **mitten** auf die Windschutzscheibe gekackt.
>
> **Mitten** im Sommer kriegt der eine Erkältung!

Comment: Eine gute englische Übersetzung (du hast deine anderen Fragen auf Englisch verfasst) für *mitten* ist oft **right**.

Comment: Heißt *Mitten auf der Brücke* irgendwo zwischen Anfang und Ende? aber in der Mitte der Brücke bedeutet (die Größe der Brücke / 2)?

Comment: *Mitten* heißt einfach nur: nicht am Rand.